# Android graphics.Camera not working when Target SDK 14

Tags: android, graphics, sdk, camera

When using android.graphics.Camera, and set the manifest to target any SDK below 14, it works fine.

Once I set target SDK to 14, it stop working.

Why?

**EDIT:**

I am not getting any errors, it just nor working...

Comment: Can you post the logcat output? It should work with SDK 14 and above as per http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Camera.html

Comment: @Nick no errors, it just not working

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. Have you tried cleaning the workspace and fixing the project properties? Maybe the switch from SDK <14 to SDK 14 messed something up. So you basically just see a black screen instead of the Camera preview? Are you testing it on an actual device or on an emulator?

Comment: It's not hardware camera. This graphics camera. It just not applies the transformations.

Comment: Oh, ok, sorry. I don't have an answer, then :(

Comment: So we've reached the point where you need to show some code.. You don't get any errors but your code doesn't work...

Comment: This is happening to me too on both an Android 4.1 phone and a 4.3 Nexus, but it doesn't happen on the emulator (4.2.2). I'm not sure what is causing this. Any camera code just doesn't do anything on physical devices but works fine for me on the emulator.

Answer (score 3):

Using `targetSdk="14"` automatically enables hardware accelerated rendering which does not support 3D transforms in all cases (at least not until 4.3.) How are you using the `Camera` object exactly? Clipping is what won't work well with 3D transforms and hardware acceleration.

`Camera.applyToCanvas()` will not work with a hardware accelerated Canvas. Instead, just call `Canvas.translate()`, or call `Camera.getMatrix()` and then `Canvas.concat(Matrix)`.

Comment: On every update I do camera.translate(cameraMovementSpeed, 0, 0) and then when I draw I do camera.applyToCanvas(canvas). This works on the emulator but not on my 4.3 Nexus or my 4.1 Android. I've tried with targetSDK="14", "16" and "17", with no luck. For the time being I've rolled my own simple camera class.

Comment: applyToCanvas() will not work with a hardware accelerated Canvas. Instead, just call Canvas.translate(), or call Camera.getMatrix() and then Canvas.concat(Matrix)

Comment: FWIW I just fixed this issue in our internal code base, the fix will be part of a future update of Android.